# Выполнить функцию только если ширина ниже определенной

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть элемент, при клике по которому должна выполняться функция. если ширина меньше например `700рх`, но функция работает нормально, только при перезагрузке страницы, а при расширении и сужении при клике на элемент происходит многократное срабатывание, если же я выношу условие за пределы родительской функции, то пишет что `переменная w не определена`

```js
function load() {
  h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  if (w < 700) {
    $(".art-vmenublockheader").addClass('respunse');
  } else {
    $(".art-vmenublockheader").removeClass('respunse');
  }
}
$(".respunse").click(function() {
  alert('работает')
})
$(window).resize(load);
$(document).ready(load);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="art-vmenublockheader" value="Жми!">
```

Comment: Надо записать. Ширина - ниже/выше, высота - уже/ширше. Новые правила русского языка, аднака

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызов `click` - подключает обработчик события. Получается, что при изменении размера окна вы подключаете многократно один и тот же обработчик, поэтому его выполнение при клике происходит многократно. Чтобы эта функция вела себя так как вы задумали - внесите проверку ширины внутрь обработчика, а подключение обработчика сделайте при только загрузке страницы.

Например так:

```
$(function($) { // вызывается когда готов DOM
     $(".art-vmenublockheader").click(function() {
           if ($(document).width() < 700) { //проверка ширины
               alert('работает');
           }
     });
});
```

Comment: но я так и не понял как сделать чтобы функция клик выполнялась при определенных размерах окна. Уже и класс добавлял и убирал, толку никакого все равно она запоминает то состояние элемента которое было при загрузке страницы

Comment: сделал изменения, работает теперь как написал в предыдущем комментарии

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов Дополнил ответ кодом

Comment: Все, дошло: проверка, при клике должна выполняться, а не при изменении ширины окна)